# Display coach marks view when user launches app for the first time Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I need to launch a coach marks/tutorial view over a tableview when the user launches the app for the first time. The coach marks will never display again, unless the user deletes and reinstalls the app.

I scoured the internet, but was unable to find a simple solution. Oh, I'm fairly new to Swift, so please be gentle. :)

**EDIT:**
Here is the what I used. Works great!

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSecondTime") {
            let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSecondTime")
            if launchedBefore  {
                print("Not the first launch.")
            } else {
                let VC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CoachMarksViewController")
                self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print("This the first launch.")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isSecondTime")
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `UserDefaults` class.  It's fairly normal to look there for an indicator that says your special view has been seen.  If you don't find the indicator, show the display and update the defaults so that you find it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "UserDefaults" to achieve this. In your "viewDidLoad" method check if a value let's say "isSecondTime == true" (This value you will access from "UserDefaults") then do nothing otherwise in else section show your tutorial and save the value "isSecondTime = true" in "UserDefaults". It will work according to your requirements. Check this code:

```
if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isSecondTime"))
    {
        // app already launched
    }
    else
    {
       // This is the first launch ever
       // show your tutorial.....!
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isSecondTime")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
```

**For Swift 3:**

```
let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSecondTime")
if launchedBefore  {
print("Not first launch.")
} else {
//  // show your tutorial.....!
print("First launch, setting UserDefault.")
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isSecondTime")
}
```

Comment: The request was for Swift **3**?

Comment: Yes, It is for Swift 3

Answer (score 3):

Probably this is what you need?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated);
    let kFirstLaunch = "First_launch"

    if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: kFirstLaunch) == nil) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: kFirstLaunch);
        //Show your coach marks here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this little launches manager :)

```
enum AppLaunchManager {

    // MARK: - Private Attributes
    private static let launchesCountKey = "LaunchesCount"


    // MARK: Public Enum Methods
    static func launchesCount() -> Int {
        guard let launched = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: launchesCountKey) as? Int else {
            return 0
        }
        return launched
    }

    static func registerLaunch() {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(launchesCount() + 1, forKey: launchesCountKey)
    }

    static func isFirstLaunch() -> Bool {
        return launchesCount() <= 1
    }
}
```

And in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    AppLaunchManager.registerLaunch()
    return true
}
```

Then, whenever you need just use:

```
if AppLaunchManager.isFirstLaunch() {
    /* do whatever you need */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need a bool to indicate whether to show the coach marks/tutorial that persists across the app being terminated and restarted.  The first time the app is run the bool will indicate that the coach marks must be displayed then the app will set the bool to indicate that they are no longer required.

To persist the bool you could use UserDefaults to store the bool and read it when the app starts.  Here is the link to the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) on it.

p.s. it might be nice to give the user a way to display them again as they might forget something or just dismiss them without thinking.

Comment: Adding a way for the user to display them again is a good idea. I will do that! Thank you :)